# Абстрактный класс. Наследование. Экземпляры класса

Tags: java, объекты, наследование

У меня по заданию:
Создаётся **абстрактный класс Point**. На его основе ColoredPoint и Line. На основе класса Line создать класс ColoredLine и класс PolyLine.

Вопрос в следующем: По сути Линия состоит из двух точек - "начало" и "конец". Но так как Line наследуется от **абстрактного** класса, то *я не могу создать Point begin, end - нельзя создать экземпляры абстрактного класса*. И я что-то не пойму, что делать... Я бы не делал Point абстрактным, и, соответственно, создал бы экземпляры в Line (используя, Point наподобие структуры в С/С++). Делал подобную задачу на С++, только в графике. А тут не знаю, абстрактность Point нужна по условию - что делать с Line тогда?.. Объявить там x1, y1, x2, y2 для координат двух точек? А зачем тогда его от Point наследовать?..
То ли с условием что-то, то ли я упускаю какую-то деталь...

Comment: Бред какой-то. Точка не является линией, поэтому наследование нелогично. Некорректное задание.

Comment: Тут имеется ввиду,что линию можно задать двумя точками.
Но мне посоветовали ещё вариант - без наследования:  создаётся абстрактный класс PointAbs, от него наследуются Point и ColoredPoint. А Line в таком случае просто использует Point, как я и хотел сделать. Это несколько меняет условие, но по смыслу очень близко подходит.

Comment: да, композиция - правильный путь.

Comment: Руководствуйтесь следующим принципом - если вы можете сказать, что наследник ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ родителем, то используйте наследование. В противном случае - ассоциацию (композицию и агрегацию).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Остановился на том, что абстрактным классом будет дополнительный PointAbs. А остальные будут основываться на нём.
Получилось что-то такое:

```
 package lab10;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class PointAbs
{
    protected int x, y;

    public abstract void toConsole();

    public PointAbs()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public PointAbs(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Point extends PointAbs
{
    public Point()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) 
    {
        super(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void toConsole() 
    {
        System.out.println("Point:\n");
        System.out.println("Point\'s coordinate: (" + getX() + ", " + getY() + ")\n");
    }
}

class ColoredPoint extends PointAbs
{
    private String colour;

    ColoredPoint()
    {
        super();
        colour = "Black";
    }

    ColoredPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        super(x, y);
        colour = "Black";
    }

    ColoredPoint(int x, int y, String colour)
    {
        super(x, y);
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getColour()
    {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour)
    {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public void toConsole() 
    {
        System.out.println("Colored point:\n");
        System.out.println("Point\'s coordinate: (" + getX() + ", " + getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("Point\'s colour: " + getColour() + "\n");
    }
}

class Line 
{
    protected Point begin = new Point();
    protected Point end = new Point();
    Line l;
    public Line()
    {
       begin.setX(0);
       begin.setY(0);
       end.setX(0);
       end.setY(5);    
    }

    public Line(Point begin, Point end)
    {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Line getLine()
    {
        return l;
    }

    public void toConsole() 
    {
        System.out.println("Line:\n");
        System.out.println("Begin\'s coordinate: (" + begin.getX()+ ", " + begin.getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("End\'s coordinate: (" + end.getX() + ", " + end.getY() + ")" + "\n");
    }    
}

class ColoredLine extends Line
{
    private String colour;

    ColoredLine()
    {
        super();
        colour = "Black";
    }

    ColoredLine(Point begin, Point end)
    {
        super(begin, end);
        colour = "Black";
    }

    ColoredLine(Point begin, Point end, String colour)
    {
        super(begin, end);
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getColourLine()
    {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColourLine(String colour)
    {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public void toConsole() 
    {
        System.out.println("Colored line:\n");
        System.out.println("Begin\'s coordinate: (" + begin.getX() + ", " + begin.getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("End\'s coordinate: (" + end.getX() + ", " + end.getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("Line\'s colour: " + getColourLine() + "\n");
    }    
}

class PolyLine
{
    private ArrayList<Line> rect = new ArrayList<>();

    PolyLine()
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(-1,4);
        Point p2 = new Point(4,5);
        Point p3 = new Point(5,0);
        Line line1 = new Line(p1, p2);
        Line line2 = new Line(p2, p3);
        rect.add(line1);
        rect.add(line2);
    }

    PolyLine(ArrayList<Line> rect)
    {
        this.rect.addAll(rect);
    }

    public void toConsole() 
    {
       System.out.println("Polyline:\n");
       for (int i = 0; i < rect.size(); i++)
       {
           System.out.format("Begin: %3d,", rect.get(i).begin.getX());
           System.out.print(" " + rect.get(i).begin.getY() + "\t");
           System.out.format("End: %3d,", rect.get(i).end.getX());
           System.out.println(" " + rect.get(i).end.getY() + "\n");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: абстракция не подразумевает реализаций и инициализаций. У Вас класс PointAbs описан как абстрактный, в нем же есть реализация методов и инициализация состояния.

Comment: @ИндиПутный  Вообще Java не запрещает реализацию методов в абстрактном классе. Более того цитата: "класс является абстрактным, если хотя бы один из его методов является абстрактным". У меня есть абстрактный метод to console(). Поэтому я не вижу каких-то нарушений абстракции из-за конструкторов и геттеров с сеттерами. В литературе я видел подобные примеры. На практике, возможно, как-то отличается, но моя задача сугубо учебная.

Comment: А если вас задели мои слова про наиболее верный подход к задаче. То это я писал про комментарий, где описывал данный мне совет. А не про этот ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Ну например, так:

```
abstract class Point {
   protected int x;
   protected int y;
   abstract float length();
}

class Line extends Point {
   protected int endX;
   protected int endY;

   @Override
   float length() {
      return Math.sqrt((endX-x)*(endX-x)+(endY-y)*(endY-y));
   }
}
```

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете "начальную" точку взять из Point, а "конечную" создать в Line?

Comment: У вас есть другие варианты? :)

Comment: Да не особо))) Если только отказаться от абстракции (мне кажется, для данной задачи она не очень подходит), но так как задача учебная, то это запрещенный выход. Спасибо за совет (:

Comment: Как у точки может быть длина?

Comment: именно поэтому класс `Point` абстрактный если угодно. А вообще длина точки=0

Answer (score -1):

Не согласен с ответом товарища "**Barmaley Red Star**" - написал свою реализацию...

```
abstract class APoint {
   protected int x;
   protected int y;
 }

abstract class ALine extends APoint {
   protected int endX;
   protected int endY;
   abstract float length();
}

class Line extends ALine {
   @Override
   float length() {
      return Math.sqrt((endX-x)*(endX-x)+(endY-y)*(endY-y));
   }
```

...на JAVA практики мало :-), но вроде реализация должна быть примерно такая.

Comment: Не понимаю смысл класса `ALine` - можете пояснить свою мысль?

Comment: да, конечно. не важно класс или абстракция, важен  принцип - единой ответственности описанный в книге Роберта Мартина "Чистый код", если мы создаем класс или абстракцию точка, то мы должны создавать сущности так чтобы они не выходили за рамки своих возможностей, у точки по определению не может быть длины, а вот у линии уже есть не только начальная точка, но и конечная, плюс добавляется длина.

Comment: @ИндиПутный мне по заданию и не нужна длина, у меня вывод цвета, координат точек. Вообще я выше написал, наиболее верный подход к задаче